# Connection and connection request timeout

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Http Apache Components to perform the http interactions. I need to adjust my http client. For this purpose I have two parameters: connection timeout and connection request timeout. In library documentation and in source code(no comments were found) I didn't found definition of this terms. I need to know what do they exactly mean. May be they were defined in HTTP protocol documentation but I can't find it. So, my question is what do this two terms mean and how they distinct from each other.

Comment: Try searching them without apache nor java keywords: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeout_(computing)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`HttpClient` has a way to set connection and socket timeout (`setConnectionTimeout()` and `setTimeout()`) according to the [HttpClient javadocs](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpClient.html).

`Connection timeout` is the timeout until a connection with the server is established.

`Socket timeout` is the timeout to receive data (socket timeout).

Example:

Let's say you point your browser to access a web page. If the server does not anwser in X seconds, a connection timeout will occur. But if it establishes the connection, then the server will start to process the result for the browser. If it does not ends this processing in Y seconds, a socket timeout will occur.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but still I have a problem. Here is request config builder http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html and it has three methods setConnectionRequestTimeout, setConnectTimeout, setSocketTimeout(and no comments!). So I still don't know what exactly each method does and what methods I should to use.

Comment: Ok, I finally found that getConnectionRequestTimeout returns imeout in milliseconds used when requesting a connection from the connection manager. I guess that connection manager is apache-httpcomponents library class, so I will not use it. I will use setConnectionTimeout() and setTimeout().

Comment: This is a case where the comment is more helpful than the answer.

Comment: The answer does not tell us what the connection request timeout is. Had to check the comments.

Answer (score 16):

From the documentation:

```
/**
 * Returns the timeout in milliseconds used when requesting a connection
 * from the connection manager. A timeout value of zero is interpreted
 * as an infinite timeout.
 * <p>
 * A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
 * A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default).
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Default: {@code -1}
 * </p>
 */
public int getConnectionRequestTimeout() {
    return connectionRequestTimeout;
}

/**
 * Determines the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
 * A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
 * <p>
 * A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
 * A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default).
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Default: {@code -1}
 * </p>
 */
public int getConnectTimeout() {
    return connectTimeout;
}
```

This is how the code should look:

```
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
// Connection Timeout to establish a connection
requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeoutMillis);
// Timeout to get a connection from the connection manager for the Http Client
requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(requestTimeoutMillis);
// Timeout between two data packets from the server
requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setSocketTimeout(requestTimeoutMillis);
clientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestBuilder.build());
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
```

Comment: this answer is at least talking about what was asked, unlike the accepted one. however, in which case would requesting a connection from connection manager time out? what are the implications of setting it? when should you set it? It's really quite unclear.

Comment: The connection manager could be a pool like `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`. When all connections from the pool are used, then the `ConnectionRequestTimeout` indicates how long your code should wait for a connection to be freed up.